# Domain name transfer: do you lose years left at current registrar?

Tags: domain-registrar, domain-transfer

I have a domain registered at GoDaddy. it was registered for five years (two years ago). whois records shows it will expire some time in 2015.

Now I want to transfer to Gandi. The problem is Gandi asks me to pay fee for at least for one year.

So my question is,

- If I transfer a domain, should I start paying from the beginning (losing two or what ever years left with previous registrar)?
- If so, Is it with the same policy with any registrar out there?

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for cleaning up my question. Will put more effort next time to take off your burden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Your domain is locked with the current expire unless cancelled or extended. During transfer the expire date remains unchanged. In this case its 2015+1=2016 if you extend after transfer.
2. Some registers charge transfer fees, some enforce renewals, some don't charge or enforce at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good to hear that. Now the ambiguity is whether gandi is asking for one year renewal or transfer charge. it just says "transfer(one year)". I should contact them.?

Comment: Normally that means your domain req a year or more, so you shouldnt need to as you have 2 years... always best to ask mind.

Answer (score 5):

All registrars work differently.  Some charge transfer and renewal fees, while others may not.  This can also vary based on the domain extension (.com, .net, etc.).  However, generally your existing expiration time will remain the same or be extended by the new registrar.

Depending on your domain extension, Gandi provides the following information as to what will happen with your current registration time.

http://wiki.gandi.net/dokuwiki/en/domains/transfer/table

As you can see, in most cases the expiration date is extended by one year.  In some cases (detailed above), the expiration date will remain unchanged or 1 year will be added from the transfer date.

I hope this helps!  Good luck with the transfer.

Comment: Thats informative. I am transferring to Gandi soon. Thank you, that was indeed helpful.

Answer (score 3):

### Note Maximum Registration Period and auto-renew grace period

Typically. you should expect the registration fee to add an additional year to your current renewal date. Keep in mind that the date at which you start the transfer, or the current renewal date, may result in no date extension.

For example, Google domains does not add an additional year if you transfer within 45 days of the current renewal date. Also, if you already at the maximum number of years that can be reserve for a domain, you won't see an increase.

Here's the full wording from the [Google domains policy](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9003299?ref_topic=9003137)

#### Transfer during the auto-renew grace period

> When you don’t renew a
> domain, the registrar automatically renews the domain. Then, you have
> an auto-renew grace period to cancel your domain registration. The
> auto-renew grace period is about 45 days for .com and .net domains and
> varies for other TLDs. When you cancel your registration, the
> registrar provides a refund for the registration cost.
>
> If you transfer a domain to Google Domains during the auto-renew grace
> period, you won’t see an increase in the registration expiration date
> when Google Domains adds a year because the transfer cancels the
> previous renewal. To get a refund for the other year, contact the
> previous registrar.

#### Maximum registration period

> In some cases, renewing the domain for the required one additional
> year causes the domain to exceed the maximum registration period. In
> these cases, you must wait until renewing for one year does not extend
> the total registration period beyond the maximum allowed.

Comment: The autorenew grace period is typically 45 days at gTLDs (and indeed varies a lot in other TLDs) but registrars are in now way forced to give all of that to customers and can decide on shorter timeframes. Which means the whole expiration process vary per registrar too, even in the same TLD. If you transfer during auto-renew period (bad idea) it voids the auto-renew, which explains why you get only one year added (from the transfer) and not 2 (renew then transfer). This creates major headaches for both registrars and registrants. Do not do it.

Comment: The maximum registration period is 10 years in gTLDs and often the same in other TLDs (except some not allowing multi year registrations). However what happens in case of operations crossing that depends again on the TLD. The new expiration date may be caped to 10 years (hence you pay for more than what you get at the end) or the operation can just be refused if the result would have been to cross the 10 years duration.